# Creating multiple matrices from one large matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix (`m`x`n`x`k`) where `m`x`n` are the data corresponding to specific latitude and longitude and `k` refers to the time.

I am trying to generate `k` matrices where each on is `m`x`n` so then I will have a matrix for each time step.

Is that possible with MATLAB?

Comment: Why do you need this? Why not just index it like `k=32;   A(:,:,k); %this is a m*n matrix`

Comment: I have to do further editing to this Data ( the data are sea levels at a specific location) , so the idea is to be able to make a for loop that reads the data and enables me to edit it all at the same time not each file by itself. I am still quite new with matlab.

Comment: In fact, the code I posted in the comment also allows you to get the `m*n` matrix, if you save it in some other variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other more advanced users may chime in with a better/more efficient way to do this, but I think I understand what you are asking and a possible way to do it (I'm curious as to other suggestions!)

Creating new variable names in a loop isn't straightforward in matlab, but, if you make them parts of structures then you can kind of work around it.

if `A` is your `m*n*k` matrix,

```
s = struct;

for i = 1:k
s.(['k' num2str(i)]) = A(:,:,k); % builds a field in structure s named k#
end
```

This should make a structure, `s`, that has `s.k1`, `s.k2`, `s.k3`, etc each of which is just an `m*n` matrix.

Then if you need to do other things later to all of the parts of s, you can call them in the same way using `s.(['k' num2str(i)])`

Comment: Not a bad idea! I think a cell array  is easier to index, but named fields could have advantages as well, depending on the application.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I still struggle with proper syntax when dealing with cell arrays so am always hesitant to use them, but I am getting a little better at it and maybe this would be good motivation!

Comment: Ha! True! They're a little confusing at first because you can index them in two ways. `C(1)={0}` vs `C{1}=0`. Keep practicing! There's a moment when it clicks, and you won't understand any more why you thought it was so hard. :D

Comment: thank you Cris Luenge and selene for the ideas, both are working fine,but I find the second one more efficent for my case! thanks alot again

Answer (score 2):

Given a 3D matrix `X`:

```
X = randn(10, 7, 4);
```

it is possible to split it out into individual planes, and store them all in a cell array, as follows:

```
C = mat2cell(X, size(X,1), size(X,2), ones(size(X,3),1));
```

Now, the array `X(:,:,k)`, the `k`<sup>th</sup> time step, is `C{k}`.

There are other ways to split out such a 3D array, and other ways to store each of the resulting 2D arrays, but this method is the simplest that I'm aware of.

There might not be a big difference in the syntax `X(:,:,k)` vs `C{k}`. If you repeatedly need to access each of the 2D arrays, the latter is more efficient, as the former needs to make a copy. If you only access each of them once, you will be better off extracting them as you need them, rather than creating the cell array.